# setSizePolicy() with QSizePolicy.Expanding does not work: the child does not expand to the size of the parent

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

According to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum, setting the size policy of a widget has the following effect:

> The sizeHint() is a sensible size, but the widget can be shrunk and
>   still be useful. The widget can make use of extra space, so it **should
>   get as much space as possible** (e.g. the horizontal direction of a
>   horizontal slider).

So, I expect the Yellow widget below to fill up the Green widget, but that does not happen. What did I do wrong?

[image]

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Yellow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        # Set palette
        bg = QPalette()
        bg.setColor(QPalette.Window, Qt.yellow)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(bg)

        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

class Green(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        # Set palette
        bg = QPalette()
        bg.setColor(QPalette.Window, Qt.green)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(bg)

        self.yellow = Yellow(self)

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 200
        self.height = 200 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.green = Green(self)
        self.green.resize(184, 154)
        self.green.move(10, 10)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I _think_ (but I'm not sure) you need a layout around your widget.

Comment: @TrebuchetMS you are right : ) didn't know it was needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Layout:

```
class Green(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        # Set palette
        bg = QPalette()
        bg.setColor(QPalette.Window, Qt.green)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setPalette(bg)

        self.yellow = Yellow(self)
        self.myLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.myLayout.addWidget(self.yellow)
        self.setLayout(self.myLayout)
```

Result:

[image: result]

If you add `self.myLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` the yellow widget completely covers the green one:

[image: result2]