# Pysides6 columnSpan backwards from setting

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I'm trying to create an app with a file browser that is 1/5 the width of a tab pane.

Why is the layout columnSpan backwards from what I set it?

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        layout = QGridLayout()

        layout.addWidget(FileTree(), 0, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(Tabs(), 0, 1, 1, 5)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

[image: column widths]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row and column span refer to the grid *cells* of the layout, not the ratio of each row or column.

Setting a span means that the widget (or layout) will occupy that amount of cells, not that it will be 5 times bigger, as the size of each cell depends on the size (and hint) of its content. Since you have nothing else in the other 4 columns, those cells are actually *empty*.

It works exactly like a table: when you *span* a cell to make it occupy 2 columns, but the second column has no width, the cell will keep the same size.

Note that even if you had widgets in another row and in any of those columns, this would still *not* mean that the tab widget would occupy 5 times the space of the first, especially if those widgets were small: QTreeView inherits QAbstractItemView, which by default has an *expanding* size policy in both directions.

To achieve the wanted ratio, you must use [`setColumnStretch()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#setColumnStretch), and *not* set any span unless you actually need it for widgets in other rows:

```py
        layout.addWidget(FileTree())
        layout.addWidget(Tabs(), 0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 5)
```

Comment: By chance is there a way to set the expanding size policy to off?

Comment: @joshp see the documentation of [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html).

Comment: @musicmante, that's where I ended up, but adding `self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)` to the QTreeView doesn't do anything, and it seems it might be because it's not a layout? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276638/setsizepolicy-with-qsizepolicy-expanding-does-not-work-the-child-does-not-exp

Comment: @musicmante FYI posted question here with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71697023/qtreeview-setsizepolicy-not-affecting-size-of-tree-in-splitter

Comment: @joshp QSplitter has its own internal layout, so that's not the problem. Anyway, remember that it's usually better to use `QSizePolicy.Preferred`, otherwise the widget might not be smaller than its size hint (which is 196 pixel in width for scroll areas) and that might not be optimal, especially when using a QSplitter. Alternatively, explicitly set the minimum size (or width, in this case). Be aware that the names of those size policies might be confusing at first, ensure that you actually understand their definitions and don't be afraid to do *a lot* of testing with various combinations.