# QTreeView setSizePolicy not affecting size of tree in splitter

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside6

I'm trying to create a Filetree viewer within a splitter, but have it occupy minimum space.

```py
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        model = QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
        self.setModel(model)
        self.setRootIndex(model.index("path/to/data"))
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
```

and the splitter

```py
        splitter = QSplitter()

        splitter.addWidget(FileTree())
        splitter.addWidget(Tabs())
        splitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1)
        splitter.setStretchFactor(0, 4)
```

However, this renders with an `Expanding` size policy on the FileTree
[image: layout]

I tried adding a container layout around the FileTree (as it seems to say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54276638/setsizepolicy-with-qsizepolicy-expanding-does-not-work-the-child-does-not-exp) but it rendered the same way

```py
class FileTreeContainer(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.containter_layout = QGridLayout()
        self.containter_layout.addWidget(FileTree())
        self.setLayout(self.containter_layout)
```

Comment: `splitter.setStretchFactor(1, 4)`?

Comment: Wow... whoops! Thanks for the typo....